# SQL Server 2014 Setup Not Given the Option to Add Current User

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am installing SQL Server 2014 Express edition. However, after several install attempts, my Windows authenticated account does not have permissions to do anything within the database server, not even `CREATE DATABASE`.

During the installation, I am not given the option to assign a role to my Windows authenticated account. Below is a screenshot of the installer window, and it shows that many of the steps in the installer are "skipped", as they do not allow me to interact with them:

[image: SQL server installation screen]

That being said, is there a way to force the Express installer to show me the "Add Current User" screen that the Developer and Enterprise installers have? If not, then what can I do to add myself as a user to the database?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone's future reference, I downloaded the wrong edition. I am accustomed to the Developer and Enterprise edition, and did not realize that the [Express edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx) was split into five possible downloads:

- LocalDB (SqlLocalDB)
- Express (SQLEXPR)
- Express with Tools (SQLEXPRWT)
- SQL Server Management Studio Express (SQLManagementStudio)
- Express with Advanced Services (SQLEXPRADV)

I had tried to install `SQLManagementStudio`, which does not ship with a database. Installing `SQLEXPRADV` fixed my issue.